# Cannot call operator with argument. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected

Tags: pine-script

I have a specific condition with a series of 4 candles (1 Green and 3 Red). I am trying to create a plotshape and alertcondition that are based on the following parameters:

- There must be a series of 4 candles (the last candle must be red). The identifier for this parameter is `OneGreenTHREEred`. I created this one successfully.
- And, the last red candle of these 4 candles must close below the lower low.

The identifier for lower low is `_lh`. However, when I type `ONEGreenTHREEred < _lh`, I receive the following error:

`line 193: Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr0'='ONEGreenTHREEred'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected. Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr1'='_lh'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected`.

I guess the `OneGreenTHREEred` identifier is 'series bool', and `_lh` is 'simple float'. Is there any way to convert one of these two identifiers to series bool or simple float, so they can be compatible with each other to create a plotshape and alertcondition?

Thank you for your help

```
//@version=5
indicator("Higher high lower low and candles", shorttitle = "HH LL candles", overlay=true)


//////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////// HIGHER HIGH LOWER LOW /////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © LonesomeThecolor.blue

//@version=5
//indicator('Higher High Lower Low Strategy', overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)
lb = input.int(5, title='Left Bars', minval=1, group="Higher High Lower Low")
rb = input.int(5, title='Right Bars', minval=1, group="Higher High Lower Low")
//showsupres = input.bool(true, title='Support/Resistance', inline='srcol', group="Higher High Lower Low")
showsup = input.bool(true, title="Support only", group="Higher High Lower Low")
showres = input.bool(true, title="Resistance only", group="Higher High Lower Low")
supcol = input.color(color.lime, title='', inline='srcol', group="Higher High Lower Low")
rescol = input.color(color.red, title='', inline='srcol', group="Higher High Lower Low")
srlinestyle = input.string(line.style_dotted, title='Line Style/Width', options=[line.style_solid, line.style_dashed, line.style_dotted], inline='style', group="Higher High Lower Low")
srlinewidth = input.int(3, title='', minval=1, maxval=5, inline='style', group="Higher High Lower Low")
changebarcol = input.bool(true, title='Change Bar Color', inline='bcol', group="Higher High Lower Low")
bcolup = input.color(color.blue, title='', inline='bcol', group="Higher High Lower Low")
bcoldn = input.color(color.black, title='', inline='bcol', group="Higher High Lower Low")

ph = ta.pivothigh(lb, rb)
pl = ta.pivotlow(lb, rb)

iff_1 = pl ? -1 : na  // Trend direction
hl = ph ? 1 : iff_1
iff_2 = pl ? pl : na  // similar to zigzag but may have multiple highs/lows
zz = ph ? ph : iff_2
valuewhen_1 = ta.valuewhen(hl, hl, 1)
valuewhen_2 = ta.valuewhen(zz, zz, 1)
zz := pl and hl == -1 and valuewhen_1 == -1 and pl > valuewhen_2 ? na : zz
valuewhen_3 = ta.valuewhen(hl, hl, 1)
valuewhen_4 = ta.valuewhen(zz, zz, 1)
zz := ph and hl == 1 and valuewhen_3 == 1 and ph < valuewhen_4 ? na : zz

valuewhen_5 = ta.valuewhen(hl, hl, 1)
valuewhen_6 = ta.valuewhen(zz, zz, 1)
hl := hl == -1 and valuewhen_5 == 1 and zz > valuewhen_6 ? na : hl
valuewhen_7 = ta.valuewhen(hl, hl, 1)
valuewhen_8 = ta.valuewhen(zz, zz, 1)
hl := hl == 1 and valuewhen_7 == -1 and zz < valuewhen_8 ? na : hl
zz := na(hl) ? na : zz

findprevious() =>  // finds previous three points (b, c, d, e)
    ehl = hl == 1 ? -1 : 1
    loc1 = 0.0
    loc2 = 0.0
    loc3 = 0.0
    loc4 = 0.0
    xx = 0
    for x = 1 to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc1 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc2 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl == 1 ? -1 : 1
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc3 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc4 := zz[x]
            break
    [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4]

float a = na
float b = na
float c = na
float d = na
float e = na
if not na(hl)
    [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4] = findprevious()
    a := zz
    b := loc1
    c := loc2
    d := loc3
    e := loc4
    e

_hh = zz and a > b and a > c and c > b and c > d
_ll = zz and a < b and a < c and c < b and c < d
_hl = zz and (a >= c and b > c and b > d and d > c and d > e or a < b and a > c and b < d)
_lh = zz and (a <= c and b < c and b < d and d < c and d < e or a > b and a < c and b > d)

plotshape(_hl, text='HL', title='Higher Low', style=shape.labelup, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.black, 0), location=location.belowbar, offset=-rb)
plotshape(_hh, text='HH', title='Higher High', style=shape.labeldown, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.black, 0), location=location.abovebar, offset=-rb)
plotshape(_ll, text='LL', title='Lower Low', style=shape.labelup, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.belowbar, offset=-rb)
plotshape(_lh, text='LH', title='Lower High', style=shape.labeldown, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.abovebar, offset=-rb)

float res = na
float sup = na
res := _lh ? zz : res[1]
sup := _hl ? zz : sup[1]

int trend = na
iff_3 = close < sup ? -1 : nz(trend[1])
trend := close > res ? 1 : iff_3

res := trend == 1 and _hh or trend == -1 and _lh ? zz : res
sup := trend == 1 and _hl or trend == -1 and _ll ? zz : sup
rechange = res != res[1]
suchange = sup != sup[1]

var line resline = na
var line supline = na
//if showsupres
//    if rechange
//        line.set_x2(resline, bar_index)
//        line.set_extend(resline, extend=extend.none)
//        resline := line.new(x1=bar_index - rb, y1=res, x2=bar_index, y2=res, color=rescol, extend=extend.right, style=srlinestyle, width=srlinewidth)
//        resline
//
//    if suchange
//        line.set_x2(supline, bar_index)
//        line.set_extend(supline, extend=extend.none)
//        supline := line.new(x1=bar_index - rb, y1=sup, x2=bar_index, y2=sup, color=supcol, extend=extend.right, style=srlinestyle, width=srlinewidth)
//        supline

if showres
    if rechange
        line.set_x2(resline, bar_index)
        line.set_extend(resline, extend=extend.none)
        resline := line.new(x1=bar_index - rb, y1=res, x2=bar_index, y2=res, color=rescol, extend=extend.right, style=srlinestyle, width=srlinewidth)
        resline

if showsup
    if suchange
        line.set_x2(supline, bar_index)
        line.set_extend(supline, extend=extend.none)
        supline := line.new(x1=bar_index - rb, y1=sup, x2=bar_index, y2=sup, color=supcol, extend=extend.right, style=srlinestyle, width=srlinewidth)
        supline




iff_4 = trend == 1 ? bcolup : bcoldn
//barcolor(color=changebarcol ? iff_4 : na)


/////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////  MA1  /////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////

len1MA = input.int(defval=1, minval=1, title="Length", group="MA")
src1MA = input(close, title="Source MA1")
offset1MA = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out1MA = ta.sma(src1MA, len1MA)
//plot(out1MA, color=color.blue, title="MA1", offset=offset1MA)

Candleopen = open
Candlehigh = high
Candlelow = low
Candleclose = close

MA1color = Candleclose > Candleopen ? color.green : color.red
plot(out1MA, title="MA1", color=color.new(MA1color, 0), linewidth=1, display=display.none)


///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////  Defining green or red candles     ////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

CloseGreen = (close >= open)
CloseRed  = (close <= open)

Condition1 = CloseGreen[3]
Condition2 = CloseRed[2]
Condition3 = CloseRed[1]
Condition4 = CloseRed

ONEGreenTHREEred = Condition1 and Condition2 and Condition3 and Condition4


////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////   PLOTSHAPE AND ALERTCONDITION   ///
////////////////////////////////////////////////


ONEGreenTHREEred_below_lowerhigh = ONEGreenTHREEred < _lh


plotshape(ONEGreenTHREEred_below_lowerhigh? high : na, text="1Green\n3Red", title='1Green 3Red', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
alertcondition(ONEGreenTHREEred_below_lowerhigh, title="1 Green 3 Red", message="1 Green 3 Red")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your variables are of type `bool`.

When you have an `and` operation in a statement, you just make that variable `bool´.

```
_lh = zz and (a <= c and b < c and b < d and d < c and d < e or a > b and a < c and b > d)
ONEGreenTHREEred = Condition1 and Condition2 and Condition3 and Condition4
```

> - There must be a series of 4 candles (the last candle must be red).    The identifier for this parameter is OneGreenTHREEred. I created this
>   one successfully.
> - And, the last red candle of these 4 candles must close below the    lower low.

The following variable will return `true`, if the pattern is, 3 green and 1 red.

```
isGreen = (close >= open)  // If close is greater than open, it is a green candle
isRed = not isGreen        // If not, it is a red candle
ONEGreenTHREEred = isGreen[3] and isGreen[2] and isGreen[1] and isRed
```

The following variable will return `true` if the last candle is the lowest of last four candles.

```
_lh = ta.lowest(low, 4)
isTheLowest = low == _lh
```